# Integral including lower incomplete gamma

Tags: integration, gamma-function

I am trying to calculate the following integral:

$\int_0^\infty \frac{A}{\Gamma{(\alpha})}\gamma(\alpha,t) dt$

where A is a positive coefficient and all parameters are positive. Any help, Thanks!

Note that:

- $\gamma(\alpha,t) =\int_0^t x^{\alpha-1}e^{-x} dx$
- $\Gamma(\alpha)$ is the complete gamma function

Comment: What have you attempted towards solving the problem?

Comment: Hi Giorgio and welcome to MSE. Try to give always as many information as you can so people can help you. What is $A$? Does $A\in \mathbb{R}, \mathbb{Q}$, etc?

Comment: The integrand $\gamma(\alpha,t) \rightarrow \Gamma(\alpha)$ for large $t$. Therefore it does not tend to zero.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We start by writing out the integral, and differently denoting the domain of integration.

\begin{align*}
A\int_0^{\infty}\int_0^t x^{\alpha - 1}e^{-x}dxdt =& A \int_{0}^{\infty} \int_x^{\infty}x^{\alpha - 1}e^{-x}dtdx \\
\end{align*}
This clearly does not converge, since the integrand does not tend to $0$ as $t \to \infty$.

Comment: I've edited something in the question, I dont know if this is going to change some things. This problem has been bugging me. Sorry for the inconvenience.

Comment: Still doesn't change anything. So long as your integrand doesn't tend to $0$ as $t \to \infty$ it's never going to converge.